# border radius not rounding background in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm noticing that Firefox is not displaying my table correctly, Chrome and IE are working as desired.  Where I see the issue is on the top and bottom rows of a table.  I'm rounding the edges of the table using the following

```
table {
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.topLeft {
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
.topRight {
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
```

Then in my table I have something like this for the header row:

```
<tr bgcolor=#cc9933>
    <th width=100 align=center class=topLeft>Owner</th>
    <th width=50 class=topRight>Points</th>
</tr>
```

The problem is that with Firefox it looks like the bgcolor set in the  tag is not getting rounded.  Is Firefox messed up here, or is it that Chrome and IE are being extra forgiving for some coding mistake?

[image] Firefox 58.0.2

[image] IE 11.1770.14393.0

[image] Chrome 64.0.3282.186

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a cross-browser quirk. You can avoid it by setting the background on the cells:

```
th {
  background: #cc9933;
}
```

[Here it is in action on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLt9depe/).

---

As far as *why* this is happening, here is a quote from [the MDN documentation for `border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius):

> The behavior on internal table elements is undefined for the moment

The result is that Chrome allows `<tr>` to have `border-radius` while Firefox does not. Neither one seems to be going against the spec.

Comment: Weird, so when I open your jsFiddle example in Firefox, it looks fine.  When I add the <th> css it does change the corners, but they still have some color in the border for my specific file.  So I must have something else in the CSS that is overriding it.  I'll keep looking, but this was helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide overflow content

```
table {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, still doesn't seem to change the look in Firefox

Comment: I also tried adding the .topLeft and .topRight to the <tr> tag, but that also had no effect